# How to export high-res global images from GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I want to export a high-resolution global image in GEE so that it can be shared as an asset, but find very little information about this. The image contains several bands that results from the processing of different existing assets with their own CRS and scales. The export is working fine with lower resolutions (e.g. 1000m), but seems to fail for higher resolutions (e.g. 30m). By "seems to fail" I mean that the first export attempt runs for a couple of days, and then move to the next attempt (without explanation for the failure of the first attempt). Here is the part of the code I am using for export:

```py
    task = ee.batch.Export.image.toAsset(**{
        'image': output_map,
        'description': 'mymap',
        'assetId': 'users/username/mymap',
        'maxPixels': 1e13,
        'scale': 30,
        'shardSize': 1024,
        'crs': 'EPSG:3857',
    })
    task.start()
```

What do I need to take into account when exporting high-res global images? How can I know whether the export will succeed or if it will face some limitations? Are the limitations intrinsically different when exporting as an asset or to Google Storage?